# how to create an image without declaring it in xml file android

Tags: android, image

How to do you have an image in an activity on android without declaring it in your xml file.

I ask because the number of images (and the actual images) are determined by what the user selects in the previous activity and is then passed through via the intent.

I want to create images according to extra data in the intent essentially but running a for loop over the extradata (array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way you programatically add ImageViews to a layout...

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp =  new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
imageView.setLayoutParams(vp);        
imageView.setImageResource(R.id.drawableResource);

//You just need to create this layout to hold the images in your XML and get a reference to it...
someLinearLayout.addView(imageView);
```

Regards!

Comment: sorry could you rexplain the last line ... not really sure whats going on there

Comment: Sure, i'm saying that you are forced to have a Layout to hold all those images, so, you can declare whatever Layout you want in your XML, and then get a reference to it, so we you call "yourLayout.addView(imageView); " they will be added as child of that group view...

Comment: Hi, I understand what you mean and have implemented it (atleast i think i have) http://fixee.org/paste/dffle7e/ it is not throwing errors but the application is crashing

Comment: You dont have an id for the Layout man, add this line:  android:id="@+id/link_devices" in the Layout Tag you have...

Comment: whats the error you are getting???

Comment: did you setContentView() the XML with the layout you have?

Comment: yup i did the setContentView() ...second line in the java code, and the error i am getting is `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.ssp.LinkDevices.onCreate(LinkDevices.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at ...` and on my device just `unfortunately app has stopped`

Comment: what do you have on the line 15 on that LinkDevices class?

Comment: i think i may have the wrong import for `LayoutParams` as it is now showing as `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`

Comment: something that should have been commented out, have done that now and error is `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.ssp.LinkDevices.onCreate(LinkDevices.java:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at ` and line25 is ` link_devices.addView(imageView);`

Comment: fixed it, i was calling the wrong id. thankyou for all your help! much appreciated!!